# MySQL Stored Procedure inserts no data

Tags: mysql, procedure, database-cursor

Actually I'm trying to insert some data into a table using a cursor, and I'm getting no error. It just says:

```
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected.
```

I'm trying to get data from each field of the `testdatabase.wp_posts p` table and insert it into an existing table `testdatabase.wp_postmeta.

My syntax is:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_authors_to_prod;
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE add_authors_to_prod()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE  v_post_id        INT;
        DECLARE  v_author_id      INT;
        DECLARE  v_last_author    INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE  str              VARCHAR(500);
        DECLARE  v_first_id       INT DEFAULT 10916;

        DECLARE author_csr CURSOR FOR
        SELECT n.nid, p.id FROM testdatabase.wp_posts p
            JOIN drupaltest.srmaif_field_data_field_auther_list auth ON auth.entity_id = p.id
            JOIN drupaltest.node_field_data n ON auth.field_auther_list_nid = n.nid
            ORDER BY p.id;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_last_author = 1;

        START TRANSACTION;
            OPEN author_csr;
                author_loop:LOOP
                    FETCH author_csr INTO v_author_id, v_post_id;
                    IF  v_last_author THEN
                        SET str = CONCAT(str, '}');
                        LEAVE author_loop;
                    END IF;

                    IF v_first_id <> v_post_id THEN
                        SET v_first_id = v_post_id;
                        SET str = CONCAT(str, '}');
                        INSERT INTO testdatabase.wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
                             VALUES(v_post_id, 'authors', CONCAT(str, v_author_id));
                        SET str = 'a:2:{';
                    ELSE
                        SET str = CONCAT(str,'i:', v_author_id, ';s:5:\"', v_author_id, '\";');
                    END IF;
                END LOOP author_loop;
            CLOSE author_csr;
            SET v_last_author=0;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL add_authors_to_prod()
```

Comment: no `COMMIT` even though there's a `START TRANSACTION`?

Comment: The "affected row"-value is not a total sum of everything that happened in your procedure, but the most recent event that changed this value. A "not found" will do that, and you get 0 affected rows, so that is the expected value. The reason nothing happens seems to be, as danblack pointed out, that you do not commit your changes.

Comment: I added the `COMMIT` and nothing changed.

Comment: To debug, maybe run your procedure (in e.g. the workbench as an easy way to see the resultsets) with `select` instead of `insert` to see what happens. Also run your first select (form the cursor) a second time without the cursor, just as a select. There seems to be nothing wrong on principle with your code, but maybe your first select (the cursor) is empty, or maybe it *does* something but you don't see it because it does the wrong thing (maybe adds comment to the wrong post). Seeing the resultsets might give you a clue what is going on, it's hard for us to debug your code without data.